# Norm of matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ as operator on $\ell_p^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\ell_p^2$ denote $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the $\ell_p$ norm where $p\in[1,\infty)$. I did a computation that indicates that if $A$ is a matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, then the norm of $A$ as an operator on $\ell_p^2$ is at most $(||R_1||_q^p+||R_2||_q^p)^{1/p}$ where $R_i$ is the $i$th row of $A$, and $q$ is such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Do I in fact have equality?

Comment: Would $A = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ work?

Comment: Evaluation of operator norm between finite-dimensional $\ell_p$-spaces is NP complete. Don't hope to get an explicit formula.